# Changing a bibtex style siam.bst so that notes appear in italics

Tags: bibtex

I am using the `siam.bst` as a style for my reference, but I would like the notes to appear in *italics*. How can i modify the `.bst` file in order to do that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you proceed as follows:

- Find the file `siam.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this file and name the copy, say, `siam-emph-notes.bst`.
- Open the file `siam-emph-notes.bst` in a text editor. The program you use to edit your tex files will do fine.
- Replace all twelve [12!] instances of `note output` with `note emphasize output`.
- Save the file `siam-emph-notes.bst` either in the directory where your main tex file is located or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter method, you'll need to update the filename database of your TeX distribution suitably. If you have no idea what the preceding senctence means, I suggest you choose the former option.
- In your main tex file, change the instruction

  ```
  \bibliographystyle{siam}
  ```

  to

  ```
  \bibliographystyle{siam-emph-notes}
  ```
- Finally, perform a full recompile cycle -- LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more -- on the tex file.

Happy BibTeXing!